# LogicException: CSRF protection needs sessions to be enabled SF2

Tags: php, symfony

I installed propel and update it via composer using this command line (`php composer.phar update propel/propel-bundle`) in my symfony 2.4 web application. After updating the bundle I have been receiving `LogicException: CSRF protection needs sessions to be enabled SF2`, can someone explain to me what is the cause of an error and help me to resolve the issue.

here's whats on my composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "propel/propel-bundle": "1.2.*",
},
```

and my config.yml

UPDATE Framework

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~# in app/config/config.yml
    session: ~
propel:
    path:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel"
    phing_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/phing"
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

Comment: have you try adding `session:         ~` in framework node ?

Comment: Also, make sure your PHP's config says `session.auto_start = 0`. Symfony's session management is incompatible with `auto_start` feature.

Comment: @Noman hi I update my framework node and I receive `InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "session, fragments, http_method_override" under "propel"
`

Comment: it seems like the symfony session is working now the problem is in your propel configuration. check the propel documentation website